# Shopify Store | Position "fixed" not working as expected for external component

Tags: html, css, shopify, shopify-app

I created a Shopify Store using the in-built customiser with a Dawn Theme. Then a custom app is developed which loads a custom script and by using Shopify Theme extensions, it allow adding the custom component in the webpage. This app displays kind of like "stories" clicking on which open an overlay. The problem is this overlay cover is broken. It is expected to cover the entire screen and should be in "front" while opened.

This is the CSS applied to it:

```
.gSrhA {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

As seen in the image, the black overlay and the opened image needs to be in the front but the image banner underneath is covering it.

I tried playing around with z-index values but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be having an effect. Can someone help in identifying the issue?

Store link to see the issue live: https://paxify-dev.myshopify.com/. Password is: paxify

[image: Broken CSS issue]